# Find the top k likes in a users social network

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Not a homework question or anything of that sort. So, here is the simple problem statement:
You have a bunch of users U<sub>1</sub>, U<sub>2</sub>, ..., U<sub>n</sub>. 
Each User has a set of friends which is a subset from the total user set. U<sub>1</sub> -> U<sub>2</sub>, U<sub>5</sub>, U<sub>8</sub>, ..., U<sub>k</sub>

Similarly U<sub>2</sub> may have friends U<sub>1</sub>, U<sub>11</sub>, ..., U<sub>k2</sub>.  Now there are a bunch of "Like" entities L<sub>1</sub>, L<sub>2</sub>, L<sub>3</sub>, ... As obvious, each user likes subset of Like objects. So U<sub>1</sub>-> L<sub>1</sub>, L<sub>2</sub>, L<sub>5</sub>, L<sub>10</sub>, ... U<sub>2</sub> -> L<sub>4</sub>, L<sub>8</sub>, L<sub>10</sub>, ...

Now the question is, given a network like the above one, given a user id, we need to return the top likes in HIS network along with couple of friends who like it (friends could be no particular order).

My thoughts:
One idea is to maintain hashmaps of Users and their friends. This is global.

User-Friends HashMap

| User  |   Map of Friends and their likes |

Now per user, we will also maintain a max heap of his likes sorted by their frequency within his network. We would need some sort of disjoint set for that to start with and also the actual max heap. When the query comes in, given a userid, we retrieve the top entries from the likes heap, and for each like, we retrieve the friends who like it.

Overall, from a datastructure standpoint, we are looking at global hashmap, per User max heap, per User disjoint set.

Is that the best way to solve this problem. I am totally lost : ( : (
Suggestions more than welcome.  Is there anything like a shortest path/bfs/dfs that we can employ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now per user, we will also maintain a max heap of his likes sorted by their frequency within his network.

Why? This would mean that you're constantly maintaining the answer to your query for EVERYONE, not just the people you get asked about. So any changes to your graph now become much more expensive because you have to update all those heaps. Plus each node's memory footprint, instead of being constant, depends on the number of friends he has and how many likes they have.

Just keep the graph as you described it, i.e. just the friend and like relationships.

Then, when you get a query on a user ID:

1. Make a hashmap.
2. For every like the user has, insert into the hashmap: L<sub>i</sub> -> count<sub>i</sub> (start with 1).
3. For every friend, repeat step 2. If a like already exists in the hashmap, increment its count.
4. Find the top `k` counts in your hashmap.
5. Return the result from step 4, and destroy the count hashmap.

Comment: I thought about this approach but the problem is that for every query, we have run through the list of the users friends and their likes trying to check if that friends like exists in the hashmap of the query user's likes.

Comment: My point is there has to be something more efficient/ something more manageable. Imagine doing this in  a network like facebook ! What sort of offline processing would facebook do. I am guessing they maintain the processed data elsewhere already and if there is a change, the update gets pushed to some worker node which recomputes this? But thats again pretty expensive : ( : (

Comment: This is similar to what FB does (for other queries I listened to talks about). This is actually a very fast operation. The only trick is to have all the users be on the same machine in a cluster, but there's tricks for that, too. The number of friends is a very small number, and the total number of likes is pretty small too.

Comment: The hard part starts for friends-of-friends queries. Once you go to the 3rd level, friends-of-friends-of-friends you basically hit the majority of the network. I believe the average diameter of the Italian graph is a bit less than 3. So the 3rd degree basically covers an entire country. BUT, a single level is very small. Also remember that hashmap operations are O(1).

Comment: The average user node on the FB graph has on the order of 150 friends. Some may get up to 1000. But you can easily scan 1000 nodes (and their likes), even for an on-line query.

Comment: The hashmap (or whatever struct you use) is NOT your bottleneck. Your bottleneck is reading the nodes themselves. The hard part is making sure you have some locality of reference, i.e. given a user you're able to read off his friends and likes quickly. But you need that anyway, so just leverage that for this query. What you're suggesting actually would multiply the storage requirements many times, because it would duplicate so much information. When your graph has 1B nodes you don't want to duplicate anything.